# Too many entries

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I use dual boot (Ubuntu along with my Windows 10).
At the time of selecting the which Operating system I need to boot, I see another option for ubuntu (Advanced options for ubuntu). When I select this option, I have a huge list (attached the screenshot).

Can anyone help me to understand what this list is about ?

Thanks in Advance

[CLICK HERE FOR THE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebNhc.jpg)

Comment: As you were asking elsewhere, yes you can delete the old kernel versions.  It is a good idea to keep one current and one older, known-to-work version installed.  There is not really any reason to keep more than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your screenshot, you should see that each entry is slightly different. As you go down the list, the string of numbers at the end of each entry decreases. These numbers are the Linux kernel versions. This is allowing you to run Ubuntu on a different kernel version.

There should be two entries for each kernel version -- one normal, one Recovery mode. That speaks for itself.

If you want to remove old kernels, run:

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

If you'd like to setup your system to automatically remove old versions once it updates the kernel, you can run:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

When the file opens, uncomment this line and set it to "true":

`//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around CPLOOK318. Do all those previous entries any disk space ? If they occupy huge diskspace, can I go ahead and delete the older kernal versions ? And is there any harm in deleting those kernal versions ?

Comment: @lavangam Haha, no problem! By the way, you can set an answer as the "answer to your question" by clicking the check beneath the up and down arrows on the left of my answer.

Comment: @lavangam Check my answer, I just edited it.

Comment: Great help !! Thanks a lot, will try your suggestions once am back at home this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment, but the easiest way to uninstall the kernels is by using Synaptic Package Manager.

Click on the "Search" and search for "linux" then click on the "$" (first column). You can remove all older versions of the kernel but I suggest your keep the current and the second most current one.